# Stochastic patterns in permutations

Tags: real-analysis

I'm a retired computer engineer and I'm studying a bit of abstract algebra these days.

I have done some research on the permutation groups of puzzles I've had a copy of the full partition of the 2x2x2 Rubik's cube for a while, and I think I can say it has an interesting structure, this partition.

It's embedded in $Z^2$, but really it has a 3 dimensional structure, you can roll up a section as a cylinder, so each section is a torus, and all the tori are nested. I figured out how to use the metric the authors used to count all the permutations, to embed the flat tori as a nested structure of open 'boxes' in $Z^3$.

I can demonstrate how this is all done with (what I think I've learned about) restriction and induction. I think the puzzles, along with a partition or part of one, are a good learning tool. Lots of ways to look at different things, apart from a color map.

But about the stochastic thing; this is about counting those permutations of a puzzle which are a pattern of some kind, and how to classify them. Does anyone have any background or hints?

Comment: Your question may look too broad for this site. This could draw downvotes and closevotes. Maybe it’s better make your question more specific.

Comment: It's hard for me to understand what is exactly your question. 1) What are the *stochastic* aspects you mention twice : where are the probabilities ? What do you mean by the terms "restriction" and "induction"  ? When you mention "puzzles", which puzzles ? What is the meaning of the sentence "Lots of ways to look at different things, apart from a color map.". Etc. Sorry, but your question, in its present state is too allusive...

Comment: There is an abundant litterature on Rubik's cube, in particular on this site. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/64440/305862) in a comment by Willie Wong an excellent Harvard reference.

Comment: Afterthought : I understand now your question as "I have found something, I can present it to you, in order you say me what are your "feelings" about it and how I can go further. If it is so, please do insert the main "findings" of your research into this question ; I will surely react.

Answer (score 0):

Are your "imbricated torii" more or less in connection with the following kind of "flattened representation" of the Rubik's cube ?

[image]

Comment: Extracted from this excellent [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wL3uWO-KLUE8)